# Curvature when extrapolated using Natural Cubic Spline

Tags: python, scipy, spline

One of the assumptions behind the [Natural Cubic Spline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_(mathematics)) is that at the endpoints of the interval of interpolation, the second derivative of the spline polynomials is set to be equal to 0. I tried to show that using the Natural Cubic Spline via  `from scipy.interpolate import CubicSplines` in the example (code below).

```
from scipy.interpolate import CubicSpline
from numpy import linspace

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

runge_f = lambda x: 1 / (1 + 25*x**2)

x = linspace(-2, 2, 11)
y = runge_f(x)
cs = CubicSpline(x, y, bc_type = "natural")
t = linspace(-5, 5, 1000)

plt.plot(x, y, "p", color="red")
plt.plot(t, runge_f(t), color="black")
plt.plot(t, cs(t), color="lightblue")

plt.show()
```

[image: Natural Cubic Spline extrapolation]

In the presented example, the extrapolated points' curvature is not equal to zero - shouldn't the extrapolation outside the interval be linear in the Natural Cubic Spline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The curvature (second derivative) of the spline at the end points is indeed 0, as you can check by running this

```
print(cs(x[0],2), cs(x[-1], 2))
```

which calculates second derivatives at both ends of your `x` interpolation interval. However that does not mean the spline is flat *beyond* the limits -- it continues on as a cubic polynomial. If you want to extrapolate linearly outside the range, you have to do it yourself. It is easy enough to extrapolate flat: replace your `cs=..` line with

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
cs = interp1d(x,y,fill_value = (y[0],y[-1]), bounds_error = False)
```

to get something like this:
[image: extrapolate flat]

but a bit more work to extrapolate linearly. I am not sure there is a Python function for that (or rather I am sure there is one I just don't know what it is)